# Laravel 5.6 Application In Production

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

When am trying to migrate anything , then every-time it's asking me about

> Do you want to run ".env" instead?  (yes/no) [no]:

I added .env file in my project. also i tried to solve this problem with this below changes :

## config/app.php

```
'.env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

## .env file below :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEGUG = true
```

i also tried to fix this problem with

```
php artisan config:clear
after this
php artisan key:generate
```

Nothing changes when i checked this current mode by :

```
php artisan env
```

It's showing me

> Current application environment: production

how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you try caching it again? `php artisan config:cache`. Also change back `'.env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),` to `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),`. `.env` is not a valid key. Also `APP_DEGUG` has a typo in your `.env` file.

Comment: @Fjarlaegur thank you so much sir. Not working . When i change config.php which inside of bootstrap/cache/config.php i just changed APP_KEY and APP_ENV there and finally its working.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and these steps helped me:

1. clear config

   `php artisan config:clear`
2. after this `php artisan key:generate`
3. now cmd say me its local

   `php artisan env`

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo:

Not:

```
'.env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),
```

But:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),
```

without dot before env